# 'int' object is not subscriptable, using elements of elements

Tags: list, python-3.x, element

No matter what I try, it keeps saying 'int' object is not subscriptable. Can someone help me?

```
    thing1 = ['Thing 1',1,1]
    thing2 = ['Thing 2',2,2]
    thing12 = [thing1,thing2]
    thing3 = thing12[0[0]]
    print(thing3)
```

This is just an example of what I did. I know I did something wrong.

Comment: I wish I was born as a psychic but unfortunately I wasn't. It would do everyone good if you can specify what is it that you want to do?

Comment: I'm trying to get it to print 'Thing 1'

Comment: You need to change the way you put your indexer: `[0[0]]` is definitely incorrect. What you want in `thing3`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm also not psychic, but it looks like you want to change

```
thing3=thing12[0[0]]
```

to

```
thing3=thing12[0][0]
```

or similar.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change your indexing:

```
thing3 = thing12[0[0]] #wrong, you try to do indexing on 0 which is an integer
```

change that into

```
#to get thing1 by thing12[0], get the first item of thing12[0] by thing12[0][0]
thing3 = thing12[0][0]
```

The error occur because of `[0[0]]` -> that is, you want to try indexing an `int`

> 'int' object is not subscriptable